# For Loops to perform a Step of 3 only after inserting a value into 6 rows of cells

Tags: excel, vba

The following code I have Will paste a value code of "01" to a cell and then skip 4 rows continuously, until reaching the end of count within the for loop. I want to run a similar loop for "02", but rather than "Step" (skip) 4 rows, I would like it to insert the value in 6 consecutive rows within the same column and then skip 3 rows continuously until reaching the end of count. I am 2 weeks new to vba, so I hope I am explaining this correctly.

```
Dim i As Long

If Sheet3.Range("C22").Value = "01" Then

    For i = 3 To 202 Step 4
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CrewEntries").Cells(i, 6).Value = _
                  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MonData").Cells(22, 5).Value
    Next i

ElseIf Sheet3.Range("C22").Value = "02" Then
    For i = 3 To 152
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CrewEntries").Cells(i, 6).Value = _
                  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MonData").Cells(22, 5).Value
    Next i

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```vb
Dim i As Long, v

v = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MonData").Cells(22, 5).Value

If Sheet3.Range("C22").Value = "01" Then

    For i = 3 To 202 Step 4
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CrewEntries").Cells(i, 6).Value = v
    Next i

ElseIf Sheet3.Range("C22").Value = "02" Then
    
    For i = 3 To 152 Step 9 '6 filled + 3 empty = 9
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CrewEntries").Cells(i, 6).Value = v
    Next i

End If
```

Comment: Im getting an object error for this. I want an outside loop not step, but go to the max.

Comment: So you don't want to go to 152 ?  Not sure what you mean by "outside loop".  This code steps in 9's (6 filled cells plus 3 empty cells)

Answer (score 0):

For such a kind of question, I would advise a while-loop, as in this piece of pseudo-code:

```
dim condition as boolean
dim loop_step, interesting_value as integer

condition = true
loop_step = 1 'just in order to be sure that it never is 0, this might create an infinite loop
interesting_value = 0 ' or some other initialisation value

while condition do 
  if <some_first_condition> 
  then
    do_first_thing(interesting_value, ...) 
    loop_step = 3
  else
    do_second_thing(interesting_value, ...)
    loop_step = 6
  end if

  interesting_value = interesting_value + loop_step  

  if <some_other_condition> then condition = false

Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub EarningCode()

Dim CpID As String

Dim i As Long

Dim p As Long

CpID = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MonData").Cells(22, 3).Value

For i = 3 To 452

If p = 9 Then

    p = 1

Else

p = p + 1


End If

If p < 7 Then

     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CrewEntries").Cells(i, 4).Value = "02"

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This ended up working for me. declared to variables, one to control the written cells and the other to control the count. This gave me a nice space between cells that I wanted to be left blank.